# Export success and failure in powershell

Tags: powershell, installation

I have a script to copy an .exe file from a network share to all devices in a .txt file and then run an install.  What I would like to do is see if I can get a confirmation if the process was complete (device offline/not pingable, install failed but file copied, etc.)  I would assume that there would be two different point at which it would export the success/failure, based on that.  One after the file copy and one after the install command.  Does anyone have a better way to do that within powershell?

```
$file = "fileSourcePath.exe"
$computerName = Get-Content "path\Workstations.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computerName) {
   Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "destinationPath"

   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
      Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "FileLocationPath"
      }
   }
```